# How do I initialize my replacement 5s iphone?

Tags: iphone

My phone was stolen but I got an insurance replacement.  How do I initialize an iPhone 5s?

Comment: What do you mean with initialize? Do you have a backup you can't restore? Or what is your problem?

Comment: My phone was stolen and I got a replacement from insurance.  The directions said I needed to initialize my new phone but doesn't tell me how. Thanks

Comment: I think I should have said "activate" instead of "initialize".

Comment: Insert a simcard and add the USB cable in order to connect it with iTunes and you will be fine. There's not many more required to activate an iPhone.

Comment: You could always read the 1-page instruction leaflet that came with it.

Answer (score 1):

Like Rob said in the commenct, insert a sim card and conect the iPhone to iTunes. You will be able to configure your iPhone on the device itself and via iTunes. When you have a backup in iCloud or in iTunes on your mac/pc, you can restore all your data from your old iPhone.